# Export Fetch function in server side to client side Node.js

Tags: node.js, json, fetch

I am new to Node.JS and Svelte. I have no prior knowledge of how to fetch JSON data to the client side using NODE.JS.

My main aim is to define a DataService.JS file that mainly fetches the JSON once and can be called in other files.

This is what I have for my DataService.JS

DataService.js

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch")
const url = "http://localhost:3000/api/tables.json"; 

const info = fetch(url)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));

//im trying to export the function.
export const getTable = ()=>{
   console.log(data);
    return data;

}
```

And this is how I called in my Catalog.svelte.

Catalog.svelte:

```
<script>
export let segment;
import DistSchema from '../components/DistSchema.svelte'; //call DistSchema components

import {info} from '../routes/main.js';

info();   //--> 500 require is not defined error

</script>
<DistSchema {segment}/>

<div id='app'>

</div>
```

My motive for doing this is because I need to display the JSON data in HTML. Any advice on how to achieve this?

My JSON file:

```
[
    {"table_schema": "a", "table_name": "a1"},
    {"table_schema": "a", "table_name": "a2"},
    {"table_schema": "a", "table_name": "a3"}, 
    {"table_schema": "b", "table_name": "b1"},
     {"table_schema": "b", "table_name": "b2"}
]
```

And i would like it to be displayed in my HTML in list format

Answer (score 0):

You can export `Promise` object returned by the `node-fetch`

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch")

export function info() {
  return fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/tables.json').then(response => response.json());
}
```

This will export the function from the current file. Now, when we need to use the resolved response in another file, import it first

```
import { info } from '<relative_file_path_of_info_function>';
```

Then, you can resolve the Promise returned from info() function like,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>JSON Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myData"></div>
    <script>
           info()
            .then(function (data) {
                appendData(data);
            })
        function appendData(data) {
            var mainContainer = document.getElementById("myData");
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var div = document.createElement("div");
                div.innerHTML = 'Schema: ' + data[i]. table_schema + ' ' + data[i]. table_name;
                mainContainer.appendChild(div);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can use something like this in `html`

Comment: may i ask "use the value here (Referenced by jsondata)",  means accessing the data from json file? and it shld be in the .js file? how do i display the value in html

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Thank you for the detailed steps for retrieving it. U surely have helped me display the data. However, I'm using svelte framework. Hence, my HTML page is .svelte and i did not have to declare the <head> and <body> tag in my catalog.html. So how do i append the script in the Html? When i tried to call the method from server, i got 500 require is not defined error. I have updated my catalog.html code above

Comment: Im sorry but it seems like i got an error saying fetchData().then(function (data) {
                                                                                             

TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined